# How to expand a bash variable in bitbake?

Tags: bash, bitbake

I have a bitbake class which has a bash function.

```
create_iso(){

xorriso_opts=" \
-outdev ${ISO_DIR}/${ISOFILE} \
-system_id ${VOLNAME} \
-volid ${VOLNAME} \
-compliance 'iso_9660_level=3':'lowercase':'deep_paths':'long_paths':'long_names':'no_force_dots':'no_j_force_dots' \
-map ${RECOVERY_DIR}/ / \
-append_partition 2 'FAT16' ${ISO_DIR}/${FAT_FS_IMG} \
-commit \
-end \
"
xorriso ${xorriso_opts} 1>/dev/null 2>&1
}
```

All the variables inside xorriso_opts are expanded, ISO_DIR points to the directory etc., but when xorriso is called with ${xorriso_opts}, the variable xorriso_opts is not expanded.

The function looks like this in the run file generated by bitbake:

```
create_iso() {
    xorriso_opts=" \
    -outdev /home/arnold/project1/build/tmp-glibc/work/project1/iso/RECOVERY.iso \
    -system_id RECOVERY \
    -volid RECOVERY \
    -compliance 'iso_9660_level=3':'lowercase':'deep_paths':'long_paths':'long_names':'no_force_dots':'no_j_force_dots' \
    -map /home/arnold/project1/build/tmp-glibc/work/project1/recovery/ / \
    -append_partition 2 'FAT16' /home/arnold/project1/build/tmp-glibc/work/project1/iso/FAT_FS_IMG.img \
    -commit \
    -end \
    "

    xorriso ${xorriso_opts} 1>/dev/null 2>&1
}
```

Is there any trick in bitbake when running command with arguments given in a variable?

Comment: What do you mean it "isn't expanded"? `xorriso` sees the literal string `${xorriso_opts}` or something else? You should probably also see [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for why sticking commands/arguments in strings like this is a bad idea.